# Clustered Vert.x not working in docker if vert.x instance is created manually

Tags: docker, vert.x

I setup a small project for learning the capabilities of Vert.x in a cluster environment but I'm facing some weird issues when I try to create the vertx instance inside a Docker image.

The project consists just in 2 verticles being deployed in different Docker containers and using the event bus to communicate with each other

If I use the vertx provided launcher:

```
    Launcher.executeCommand("run", verticleClass, "--cluster")
```

(or just stating that the main class is `io.vertx.core.Launcher` and putting the right arguments)

Everything works both locally and inside docker images. But if I try to create the vertx instance manually with

```
Vertx.rxClusteredVertx(VertxOptions())
        .flatMap { it.rxDeployVerticle(verticleClass) }
        .subscribe()
```

Then it's not working in Docker (it works locally). Or, more visually

```
|                   | Local     | Docker    |
|:---------------:  |:-----:    |:------:   |
|  Vertx launcher   |   Y       |    Y      |
| Custom launcher   |   Y       |    N      |
```

By checking the Docker logs it seems that everything works. I can see that both verticles know each other:

```
Members [2] {
    Member [172.18.0.2]:5701 - c5e9636d-b3cd-4e24-a8ce-e881218bf3ce
    Member [172.18.0.3]:5701 - a09ce83d-e0b3-48eb-aad7-fbd818c389bc this
}
```

But when I try to send a message through the event bus the following exception is thrown:

```
WARNING: Connecting to server localhost:33845 failed
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:33845
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ... 11 more
```

Just for simplifying stuff I uploaded the project [to Github](https://github.com/AlbertoSH/clustered-vertx-issue). I tried to make it as simple as possible so it has 2 verticles & 2 main classes and lots of scripts for every combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By researching a bit more into the Vert.X [`Launcher`](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/Launcher.java) code I found out that internally it's doing more things than just "parsing" the inputs

In case vertx is configured to run in cluster mode the `Launcher` is setting the cluster address itself (via [`BareCommand`](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/impl/launcher/commands/BareCommand.java#L165) class) so in order to replicate the `Launcher` behaviour with your own `Main` class (and having the flexibility to configure your vertx instance via code instead of via args) the code will be as follow:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    Vertx.rxClusteredVertx(
            VertxOptions(
                    clusterHost = getDefaultAddress()
            )
    )
            .flatMap { it.rxDeployVerticle(verticleClass) }
            .subscribe()
}


// As taken from io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.BareCommand
fun getDefaultAddress(): String? {
    val nets: Enumeration<NetworkInterface>
    try {
        nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
    } catch (e: SocketException) {
        return null
    }

    var netinf: NetworkInterface
    while (nets.hasMoreElements()) {
        netinf = nets.nextElement()

        val addresses = netinf.inetAddresses

        while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
            val address = addresses.nextElement()
            if (!address.isAnyLocalAddress && !address.isMulticastAddress
                    && address !is Inet6Address) {
                return address.hostAddress
            }
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> By checking the Docker logs it seems that everything works. I can see
>   that both verticles know each other

Yes, because your cluster manager works fine, but you should also make your event bus configuration be consistent in every node (machine/docker container) in your cluster because as mentioned in Vert.x documentation: cluster managers do not handle the event bus inter-node transport, this is done directly by Vert.x with TCP connections.
 
You have to set the cluster host on each node to be the IP address of this node itself and any arbitrary port number (unless you try to run more than Vert.x instance on the same node you have to choose a different port number for each Vert.x instance). The error you are facing is because the default cluster host is `local host` 
 
For example if a node's IP address is 192.168.1.12 then you would do the following:

```
VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions()
                .setClustered(true)
                .setClusterHost("192.168.1.12") // node ip
                .setClusterPort(17001) // any arbitrary port but make sure no other Vert.x instances using same port on the same node
                .setClusterManager(clusterManager);
```

on another node whose IP address is 192.168.1.56 then you would do the following:

```
VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions()
                .setClustered(true)
                .setClusterHost("192.168.1.56") // other node ip
                .setClusterPort(17001) // it is ok because this is a different node
                .setClusterManager(clusterManager);
```

Comment: This would work if the cluster IP would be known at compile time, which is not the case. I researched about how vertx Launcher does this at added as response